# MongoDB $lookup on nested document, limit and count the retrieved data

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

I would like to get a count of all notifications that aren't read by an User ("A", "B", "C", etc) for each subRoom. Taking into account that it could be millions of notifications documents and hundreds of subrooms elements in Rooms Collections, i need to limit it. For that reason I've limited the $lookup for first 100 elements and then check if that notifications have been read or not by an User. I did it using documents (roomId) in $lookup but I cant do it using subdocuments (subRoom.id).

Notifications Collection is indexed using a Compound of (roomId: 1, timestamp: -1)

**Notifications Collection:** (id corresponds to notification id and roomId is the link to Rooms collection)

```
[{
    "_id": "XXX",
    "id": "1",
    "read": ["A", "B", "C"],
    "roomId": "c1d87a4c-231d-4cc8-8438-35cf21ed7fc5",
    "content": "XXX",
    "timestamp": { "$date": "2021-12-31T22:50:53.000Z"  }
},{
    "_id": "XXX",
    "id": "2",
    "read": ["C"],
    "roomId": "c1d87a4c-231d-4cc8-8438-35cf21ed7fc5",
    "content": "XXX",
    "timestamp": { "$date": "2021-12-31T22:50:53.000Z" }
},
...
]
```

**Rooms Collection:**

```
[{
    "_id": "XXX"
    "subRoom": [{
        "id": "c1d87a4c-231d-4cc8-8438-35cf21ed7fc5",
        "image": "XXX",
        "name": "XXX"
    }, {
        "id": "c2d5081e-0cf1-4e69-937d-be357da1d104",
        "image": "XXX",
        "name": "XXX"
    }, {
        "id": "530c2c02-26e8-441c-af39-c5232dfe1f73",
        "image": "XXX",
        "name": "XXX"
    }],
    "id": "453a6458-6545-4842-8946-05f49efea216",
    "name": "XXX",
},
...
]
```

**Code working using roomId instead subRoom.id:**

```
   { $lookup: {
      from: "notifications",
      let: { "id": "$id" },
      pipeline: [
        { $match: {
          $expr: 
              { $eq: [ "$roomId", "$$id" ] }
        }},
        { $limit: 100},
        { $project: {_id: 0, read: 1}}
      ],
      as: "messages"
    }},
   { $project: {_id: 0, id: 1, notRead: {
     $size: {
       $filter: {
          input: "$notifications",
            cond: {
              $not: {
                 $in: [
                   "A",
                   "$$this.read"
                  ]
                }
             }
          }
       }
    },
 }
```

**Code NOT WORKING using subRoom.id:**

```
 { $lookup: {
      from: "notifications",
      let: { "id": "$subRoom.id" },
      pipeline: [
        { $match: {
          $expr: 
              { $eq: [ "$roomId", "$$id" ] }
        }},
        { $limit: 100},
        { $project: {_id: 0, read: 1}}
      ],
      as: "messages"
    }},
    {
      $addFields: {
        items: {
          $map: {
            input: { $zip: { inputs: ["$subRoom", "$messages"] } },
            in: { $mergeObjects: "$$this" },
          },
        },
      },
    },
   .
   . projection
   .
```

**Expected Result:**

```
 [{
        "_id": "XXX"
        "subRoom": [{
            "id": "c1d87a4c-231d-4cc8-8438-35cf21ed7fc5",
            "notRead": 50 //e.g
        }, {
            "id": "c2d5081e-0cf1-4e69-937d-be357da1d104",
            "notRead": 35 //e.g
        }, {
            "id": "530c2c02-26e8-441c-af39-c5232dfe1f73",
            "image": "XXX",
            "notRead": 5 //e.g
        }],
        "id": "453a6458-6545-4842-8946-05f49efea216",
        "name": "XXX",
    },
    ...
]
```

***Finally and very importantly, I want an scalable solution that can be done with big data.***

Thank you very much in advance.

Comment: are you trying to get to notRead count for particular role right?

Comment: I'm trying to get notRead count for particular user. notRead property is an array of "UsersId" who have seen the notification. I simplified for the example using "A", "B", "C" instead of uuid.

Comment: can you verify this [playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/RhNizn91mdx).

Comment: At first glance it seems correct. I am going to test it now with millions of records to see if it takes little time to do the searches and I am going to limit the lookups to 100 documents (having it indexed by timestamp: -1, it should check the latest notifications by date). One more thing, would there be any way for the variable "notRead" to appear when the count is 0? Thank you very much @turivishal, I hope I can do something to reward for the effort.

Comment: use `$sum` instead of `$first` in `$addFields`.

Comment: Working fine with 50M documents so if you want, write the answer of my question and I'll validate it. Thank you very much...

Comment: I have added a second option as well, i am not sure about performance but you can test may it will help you.

Comment: I'll  check it and I'll tell you which one is better. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- `$unwind` deconstruct `subRoom` array with preserve null and empty array property
- `$lookup` with notification collection using pipeline, `let` to pass `id` to pipeline, check condition for `roomId` and user should not read notification
- `$group` by null and count total unread notifications
- `$addFields` to get count to notifications using `$sum`
- `$group` by `_id` and reconstruct the `subRoom` array with required fields in result

```
db.rooms.aggregate([
  {
    $unwind: {
      path: "$subRoom",
      preserveNullAndEmptyArrays: true
    }
  },
  {
    $lookup: {
      from: "nitifications",
      let: { id: "$subRoom.id" },
      pipeline: [
        {
          $match: {
            $and: [
              { $expr: { $eq: ["$$id", "$roomId"] } },
              { read: { $ne: "A" } }
            ]
          }
        },
        {
          $group: {
            _id: null,
            count: { $sum: 1 }
          }
        }
      ],
      as: "subRoom.notRead"
    }
  },
  {
    $addFields: {
      "subRoom.notRead": { $sum: "$subRoom.notRead.count" }
    }
  },
  {
    $group: {
      _id: "$_id",
      name: { $first: "$name" },
      id: { $first: "$id" },
      subRoom: { $push: "$subRoom" }
    }
  }
])
```

[Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/dolwlPNNGWz)

---

Second option without using `$unwind` stage,

- `$lookup` with notification collection using pipeline, `let` to pass `id` to pipeline, check condition for `roomId` and user should not read notification
- `$group` by null and count total unread notifications
- `$map` to iterate loop of `subRoom` array
- `$filter` to iterate loop of return result from lookup notifications count and get current `subRoom` document
- `$let` to declare a variable `n` and assign above filtered result to it and return `$sum` from `count`
- `$mergeObjects` to merge current object of `subRoom` and new field `notRead`

```
db.rooms.aggregate([
  {
    $lookup: {
      from: "nitifications",
      let: { id: "$subRoom.id" },
      pipeline: [
        {
          $match: {
            $and: [
              { $expr: { $in: ["$roomId", "$$id"] } },
              { read: { $ne: "A" } }
            ]
          }
        },
        {
          $group: {
            _id: "$roomId",
            count: { $sum: 1 }
          }
        }
      ],
      as: "notRead"
    }
  },
  {
    $project: {
      id: 1,
      name: 1,
      subRoom: {
        $map: {
          input: "$subRoom",
          as: "s",
          in: {
            $mergeObjects: [
              "$$s",
              {
                notRead: {
                  $let: {
                    vars: {
                      n: {
                        $filter: {
                          input: "$notRead",
                          cond: { $eq: ["$$this._id", "$$s.id"] }
                        }
                      }
                    },
                    in: { $sum: "$$n.count" }
                  }
                }
              }
            ]
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
])
```

[Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/7g8ctsJUlxb)